# Optimising event handling: one large, or many small?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which pattern is best, and why?

```
$myElements.delegate(selector, 'event1 event2', function () {
   if (event.type === 'event1') { /* Handle event 1 */ }
   if (event.type === 'event2') { /* Handle event 2 */ }
}
```

**OR**

```
$myElements
   .delegate(selector, 'event1', function () {
       /* Handle event 1 */
}
   .delegate(selector, 'event2', function () {
       /* Handle event 2 */
}
```

In other words, is it better to have one large unified handler, or many small separate handlers?

Comment: Better in what way? Performance when assigning the handlers? Performance when invoking the handlers? Code clarity and maintenance? Better in some other way?

Comment: Two preoccupations: assignment and invokation of handlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am fairly sure that the second solution is to be preferred. From the jQuery source:

```
// Handle multiple events separated by a space
// jQuery(...).bind("mouseover mouseout", fn);
types = types.split(" ");
```

So there is the step of splitting a string and then running through a while loop for each event. In the first case the handler is called for every event and then your if statement is executed. In the second only the handler actually attached is being called.

Besides, the second version is a lot easier to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to use the second one

http://jsperf.com/lklklklklklklklklk

second one is probably faster